# How to combine time series in matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series

I have two time series objects:

Accelerometer, with 591755 samples in the form:

```
    Time             X                Y            Z
1   181135620117     0.21547815       9.740809     0.11133038
2   181140258789    -0.027533319     10.150218     0.08738836
3   181145629882    -0.22984336      10.376471     0.16519992
    ...
```

Gyroscope, with the same amount of samples:

```
    Time            X             Y               Z 
1   181135620117   -0.08841695   -0.023435818    -0.15233281
2   181140258789   -0.09161274   -0.027696876    -0.15126754
3   181145629882   -0.07456851   -0.024501082    -0.13209279
a   ...
```

The time is in nanoseconds. I want to produce a matrix with columns like this:

```
    Time         X_acc   Y_acc    Z_acc    X_gyro    Y_gyro    Z_gyro
1   0            ...     ...      ...      ...       ...       ...
2   0.005        ...     ...      ...      ...       ...       ...
3   0.010        ...     ...      ...      ...       ...       ...
    ...
```

I am brand new in Matlab, and I am really struggling with that one. I was told that I can use the `resample()` function from the `timeseries` class using `zoh` interpolation method, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: Do you simply want to **concatenate** the results together, or is the `time` variable in seconds and you wish to interpolate in between 0-1, 1-2, etc. at 0.005 second intervals?  Are these "time series" objects matrices?  How are these represented?  How are you reading in or obtaining this data?  The context behind this isn't very clear.

Comment: At least tell us in which type of variable you got the data. Are they written in a mat-file, string, cell-matrix, struct, or do you have to read the file first, e.g. *.csv or *.txt?

Comment: What format is your data in?

Comment: The input data are a .txt files, the first column is the sample number, the second is the time in nanoseconds, which doesnt start from 0( i want to make it to start from 0 ), and the 3 last columns are coordinates in X, Y, Z axis.  The time variable is in nanoseconds, but i want to convert it to be in seconds and also interpolate at 0.005 intervals.. thanks

Comment: If I were you I'd first do something along the lines of `paste accelfile gyrofile |awk 'NR>1{if($1==1){t0=$2;}; print $1,($2-t0)/1e9,$3,$4,$5,$8,$9,$10;}'` (at least in linux) to do most of the nasty file manipulations, then let matlab do the interpolation. Assuming, of course, that your times are the same in each column.